# How do I retrieve address components from Place API object?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I want my user to be able to pick an address. For my backend, I need to get the following info: street name, number, country and zip code.

I am using `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` fragment as mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete.

When the user has selected a Place, I get the `Place` object as a result:

```
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        // Here I want to retrieve all the address details, such as
        // street name, number, country etc. and send them to my backend
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        //handle Error
    }
});
```

However from the `Place` object I can only use `place.getAddress()` to get a "human readable" address line.

The [iOs](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/place-details) and [JS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details) documentations both show that you can retrieve the `addressComponents`(iOs) or `address_components`(JS) from the `Place` object which contains these fields (street, zipcode, etc.). However the Android documentation shows no such method for a `Place` object for retrieving the `addressComponents`.

Am I overlooking something? Is it possible that they provide this info fro iOs and JS but not for android? Or am I also maybe missing an ovious alternative?

Comment: You can use the places web service api to get more place details based on the place ID, but in a production environment you would need to use a proxy server: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details    If you are just doing this for a small project, you can access the api directly in the app with an unsecured server api key.

Comment: Sorry, but that was ont the answer I am hoping for. Is there no way to do it with the Android API?

Comment: You can manually parse the address using a regex

Comment: i thoght about that, but it turns out that the format differs, depending on which country the address is for, so no, i m afraid i cant do that either.. :/

Comment: I have the same question. And why are the address components available on the iOS SDK but not on the Android SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the search parameters you want.

```
autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ADDRESS,Place.Field.LAT_LNG));
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/24067287).

Answer (score 0):

There is a getAddressComponents() in Place object.

Make sure to add "Place.Field.ADDRESS" in Fields list, onActivityResultresults data will have the components of the place, otherwise it will be null.

```
List<Place.Field> fieldList = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ADDRESS,
            Place.Field.ADDRESS_COMPONENTS,
            Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.UTC_OFFSET);
    Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY
            , fieldList)
            .build(context);
```